# Didn't find class "...MainApplication" on path :DexPathList

Tags: android, gradle, android-emulator, dagger-hilt

I have the following log output when launching application in emulator in Android Studio

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 10061
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.myapplication.MainApplication package com.example.myapplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myapplication.MainApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~Xi2qjD7cAym3pm1dcBBQ_w==/com.example.myapplication-DRn8-gmjtR7Q8Xgkb58OBQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~Xi2qjD7cAym3pm1dcBBQ_w==/com.example.myapplication-DRn8-gmjtR7Q8Xgkb58OBQ==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~Xi2qjD7cAym3pm1dcBBQ_w==/com.example.myapplication-DRn8-gmjtR7Q8Xgkb58OBQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1466)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1395)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6959)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2236)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myapplication.MainApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~Xi2qjD7cAym3pm1dcBBQ_w==/com.example.myapplication-DRn8-gmjtR7Q8Xgkb58OBQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~Xi2qjD7cAym3pm1dcBBQ_w==/com.example.myapplication-DRn8-gmjtR7Q8Xgkb58OBQ==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~Xi2qjD7cAym3pm1dcBBQ_w==/com.example.myapplication-DRn8-gmjtR7Q8Xgkb58OBQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:51)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1282)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1458)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1395)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6959)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2236)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/example/myapplication/Hilt_MainApplication;
at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myapplication.Hilt_MainApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~Xi2qjD7cAym3pm1dcBBQ_w==/com.example.myapplication-DRn8-gmjtR7Q8Xgkb58OBQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~Xi2qjD7cAym3pm1dcBBQ_w==/com.example.myapplication-DRn8-gmjtR7Q8Xgkb58OBQ==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~Xi2qjD7cAym3pm1dcBBQ_w==/com.example.myapplication-DRn8-gmjtR7Q8Xgkb58OBQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
... 19 more
```

My build.gradle on project level

```
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"}
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.10"
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.48'
    }

    ext {
        compose_ui_version = '1.5.1'
        testRunnerVersion = '1.5.2'
        testJunitVersion = '1.1.5'
        truthVersion = '1.5.0'
        espressoVersion = '3.5.1'
        androidXTestVersion = '1.5.0'
        testRulesVersion = '1.5.0'
        ksp_version = '1.5.31'
        kotlin_version ='1.7.20'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.10' apply false
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.10'  apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version "2.48" apply false

}

allprojects{
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.9.10'
        }
    }
    repositories {
    }
}
```

On app level

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'idea'
    id("org.jetbrains.dokka") version "1.8.20"
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
    id "kotlin-kapt"
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.myapplication'
    compileSdk 34


    hilt {
        enableAggregatingTask = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 34
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.example.myapplication.CustomTestRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments += ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    java {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
        viewBinding true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.5.3'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
            exclude 'META-INF/gradle/incremental.annotation.processors'

        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    //enable multidex
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    // Compose and UI-related libraries
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.09.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-core:1.2.3'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-framework:0.1.0-dev10'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.5.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.2'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-testing:2.8.1'
    testImplementation 'org.testng:testng:7.8.0'
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.2'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.09.00')
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_ui_version"

// Networking and API libraries
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation('io.ktor:ktor-client-core:2.3.4')
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0")
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.10.0")
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.48'
    kaptAndroidTest 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.48'
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.48"

// Firebase related libraries
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.2.1'
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx")

// Dependency injection and Dagger Hilt
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.48'


// Data storage and persistence
    def room_version = "2.5.2"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0")
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.8.1'
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"

// Other utility libraries
    implementation 'com.github.androidmads:QRGenerator:1.0.1'
    implementation 'nu.aaro.gustav:passwordstrengthmeter:0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.security:security-crypto-ktx:1.1.0-alpha06'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric-ktx:1.2.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.3.0'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-view:1.2.3'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.2.3'
    implementation "io.github.jisungbin:multifab:1.0.0"
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.9'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.9'

// Testing libraries
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:5.5.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:2.28.3'
    // Core library
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core:$androidXTestVersion"

    // AndroidJUnitRunner and JUnit Rules
   ...

    // Assertions
    ....

    // Espresso dependencies
    ...

}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

My theory it has to do something with hilt or kapt, but I can not figure out what I need to do.

I tried renaming the application class, and cleaning Gradle and Android Studio caches, but the app keeps crushing on launch every time.

Comment: 1) Show your `AndroidManifest.xml` 2) Manually delete your app from the emulator before attempting to run.

Comment: Solved issue by migrating from kapt to ksp, code still does not run but because of an issue unrelated.